# Calculate the Biweekly Pay-period in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I'm trying to come up with a function to calculate the bi-weekly pay-period in Excel. For example: 7/12/11 through 7/26/2011 I want to return Fridays only, 7/21 and 8/5/2011 for Payday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not clear what you want to do exactly - do you need a list of paydays or to return a payday as a result of a date input?

Comment: I want to return a payday as a result of a date input

Comment: 21 July 2011 seems to be a Thursday. Shouldn't this be 7/22/2011? And can you explain how the payday for those dates become 7/21 and 8/5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a date in A1 then you can return the **next** payday on or after that date with this formula

`=CEILING(A1+1,14)-1`

Assuming paydays are every 2 weeks with one payday being on Friday 26 July 2013

If it's the "alternate" Fridays then switch to this version

`=CEILING(A1+8,14)-8`

Assumes you are using default 1900 date system

Comment: barry houdini: Thank you so much! That's what exactly I need!

Answer (score 1):

## GOAL:

Create a formula that will generate a biweekly-expected paydate with any input date.

### Define Biweek, & Paydate

The dates supplied at the top are 15 days apart. Biweeks are 14 days. I am assuming that a biweek is on and between Tue 7/12/2011 & Mon 7/25/2011 and that the expected paydate is supposed to be Friday 8/5/2011. I am also assuming that the biweek pattern repeats indefinitely.

- Example 1: work on 7/11/2011 should be paid on 7/22/2011,
- Example 2: work on 7/12/2011 should be paid on 8/5/2011,
- Example 3: work on 7/25/2011 should be paid on 8/5/2011, &
- Example 4: work on 7/26/2011 should be paid on 8/19/2011.

A **biweek** is 14 consecutive workdays starting on an arbitrary date **S** and ending on an arbitrary date **E**. Where **S** + 13 = **E**

An **Expected Pay Date** (**EPD**) of a biweek is always a certain number of days after **E** (The end of the biweek ) The **EPD** is usually a Friday.

### Solutions ( we will assume cell **A1** is the input date )

1. `=A1-MOD(A1,14)+IF(MOD(A1,14)<10,20,34)` *This works by converting every date to the saturday before the input date: **A1**, this is convenient because the expectated pay date will now always be 20 or 34 days away, the **IF** formula applies this appropriately.*
2. **OR** `=A1+CHOOSE(MOD(A1,14)+1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,24,23,22,21)` *this formulas works on the same subject, but rather than converting everything to saturday it utilizes the fact that with the biweek definition of all biweeks starting on and including a Tuesday and ending 13 days later on and including a Monday the **EPD** will always be 11 to 25 days off depending on the day of the week it is. The **MOD** formula determines what day of the week it is and the **CHOOSE** formula chooses the appropriate number of days to add (11 to 25).*

### MY COMPANY's BIWEEK & EXPECTED PAY DATE CONFIGURATION:

My company actually has a **biweek** that starts on a Thursday such that the 14th day of the **biweek** is a Wednesday. The **EPD** is always 16 days after the end of the **biweek** Wednesday. An arbitrary Friday that happens to be one of our **EPD**'s is 12/4/2015. With this information the two formulas above can be adjusted:

1. `=A1-MOD(A1,14)+IF(MOD(A1,14)<5,20,34)` *again all dates are converted to Saturday, but where it used to be "<10" in the **IF** formula now it is "<5" because my **biweeks** end on a Wednesday, instead of a Monday.*
2. `=A1+CHOOSE(MOD(A1,14)+1,20,19,18,17,16,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21)` *same except given my **biweek** and **EPD** definition the range is now 16 to 29 days.*

### HOW TO CHANGE IT TO FIT YOUR DATE SET:

The First formula is probably easiest for most people to use. To adjust it to fit your date Range you'll have to define figure out four things:

1. ***d*** = the input date *(this is probably a range like "A1")*
2. ***s*** = The difference between your **EPD** and **S** *(the start of your biweek)*
3. ***e*** = The difference between your **EPD** and **E** *(the end of your biweek)*
4. ***w*** = is the MOD(***s***,14)

**APPLY:** =***d***-MOD(***d***,14)+IF(MOD(***d***,14)<***w***,***e***,***s***)

**Disclaimer:** sorry if the maths are a bit complicated looking, if someone has a easier way of explaining I'm always open to it.